# Binary cannot be primary but the only column that doesn't change is binary

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a simple table with few columns which I'm accessing using **Linq2sql**. The only column that doesn't change is binary. But when I try to make it the primary column - Linq2sql tells me that:

> System.Byte[]  is not supported for identity members.

(It means primary. There's no identity in the table.)

And if I don't set any primary column linq2sql tells me that it can't work without a primary key.

And if I set a different column as primary - I can't change that column.

What would be a solution here?

Comment: Add an id column to the table?

Comment: @DaleBurrell But a primary column needs to be unique.

Comment: Yeah, add a unique id column? `alter table mytable add id int identity (1,1)`

Comment: @DaleBurrell Sorry, I wasn't clear. I assume you mean an auto increment int identity. But what if the seed is reset, won't that mean that any new insert will fail because the id will already exist in the table?

Comment: Why would reset the seed?

Comment: @DaleBurrell By human error or for whatever reason. I need something that will always create a new unique one. Can that be done?

Comment: Most people use an identity column... it won't reset itself by mistake... but you can write your own sequence generator... seems a bit OTT though.

Comment: If you don't trust the SQL server with maintaining a sequence, then how can you trust it with the actual data? An `int` identity column is good for about 2 billion rows. If you're really worried about that then use a `bigint`. You could use a `uniqueidentifier` column, but using that as a clustering key isn't perfect either.

Comment: @DaleBurrell It won't. But I try not to underestimate human fallibility.

Comment: @Dirk As I answered Dale, I didn't mean the database. I meant human error (edited to be clearer now).

Comment: @ispiro if you're worried about a person messing with your identity column, then there is always something they can do to mess with your database... remove their permissions lol you can't really remove the human factor...

Comment: Well, in addition to being immutable and unique, keys also should be narrow and ever increasing, while byte arrays aren't.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Proceeding to remove my permission... :) But seriously, I got my answer. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique id column e.g.

```
alter table mytable add id int identity (1,1)
```